# Xaml string format currency negative amount to positive

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, string-formatting

How can I format a string with negative currency amount, -19.72 CHF / € / $ ... to positive? By setting
`StringFormat="'{0:C}'"` shows positive as currency format of my culture, but negative shows negative. I've tried with `StringFormat="'{0:C; #.##}'"` which shows negative to positive but without the culture currency. Is it possible to show it as I want?

-19.72 => 19.72 CHF

I could make it work just by using a converter and multiplying by -1, but im looking for an easier solution.

Comment: Try to set  `StringFormat={}{0:#; #.##}}` .

Comment: That way I get it positive, as I mentioned in the question. What I want is to show it up with currency, like doing {0:C}, which shows currency of my current culture, but without the minus sign.

Comment: In your case use converter is the best way .